# If $M=A \cup B$ is $A \in M$, $A \subset M$, or both?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The distinction between these two symbols has always eluded me. Can someone please explain?

Comment: It represent a hierarchy. The statement $A\subset B$ means that $A$ and $B$ are objects of the same kind. But the statement $A\in B$ mean that $A$ and $B$ are objects of different kind. But this is not a formal explanation, ofc.

Answer (score 3):

It is always the case that $A \subset A \cup B$ because if $x \in A$ then $x \in A \cup B$.

It **may** be the case that $A \in A \cup B$, for example, $A = \{1\}$ and $B= \{ \{ 1 \} \}$. In this example, $A \in B$, hence $A \in A \cup B$.

Generally we try to avoid such things.

Answer (score 2):

First, some basic symbols:

- $A\in B$ means $A$ is an *element* of $B$ - that is, $A$ is part of the set $B$.
- $A\cup B$ means the *union* of the sets $A$ and $B$ - that is, all of the objects that are part of the set $A$, the set $B$, or both.
- $A\subset B$ means that $A$ is a subset of $B$ - that is, all of the elements in $A$ are also in $B$. (It should be noted that every set is a subset of itself; i.e., $A\subset A$.)

Some more basic symbols are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation).

Now, for your specific question. If $M = A\cup B$, that means $M$ contains all of the elements of $A$ and $B$. Therefore, $A$ is indeed a subset of $M$ as all of its elements are by definition in $M$, so $A\subset M$. Now, lists aren't really elements. So, if $A = \{1,2,3\}$, then $A\notin B$ ($\notin$ means $A$ is *not* an element of $B$). However, if $A$ only has a single element, for example if $A=\{1\}$, then $A\in B$, but this notation should be avoided.

Sometimes it can help to draw a venn diagram:

[image]

represents $A\cup B$ and from here we can clearly see that $A$ is indeed a subset of $M$.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

$A \subset M$ means $A$ is a subset of $M$.

Examples:  $\{Peter, Paul, Mary, Luke, John\}\subset ${people mentioned in  the bible}.  Because every element of the $\{Peter, Paul, Mary, Luke, John\}$ are each members of {people mentioned in  the bible}.

$A \in M$ means $A$ is an element of $M$.

Example $Peter \in ${people mentioned in the bible}

$\{Peter, Paul, Mary, Luke, John\} \not \in ${people mentioned in  the bible} because ..... $\{Peter, Paul, Mary, Luke, John\}$ is not a person mentioned in the bible.  THere is no person whose name is "$\{Peter, Paul, Mary, Luke, John\}$"

Example: $\{\text{even numbers}\}\subset \mathbb Z$  because the set of all even numbers is a smaller set that is completely contained in the integers.

$2 \not \subset \mathbb Z$ because $2$ is not a set at all; it's an integer.  (Oh, be quiet, you set theorists!  You can tell me all about how from a set theoretical construct of axioms everything is a set and what an idiot I am somewhere else.)

$\{\text{even numbers}\}\not \in \mathbb Z$ because $\{\text{even numbers}\}$ is not an integer.  It's a set of integers.

Basically a set is a list and a subset is a smaller list.  Members are the things *in* the list.  A shopping list are a *list* of the things you will buy.  The list, itself, is not one of the things you will buy.  If you try to eat your shopping list... it won't work.

So $M = A \cup B$.  Is $A$ an element in the set $M$? or is $A$ a smaller set composed of some of the elements of the set $M$.